# How to download file with direct link Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to download a image with puppeteer. the problem here, buffer return by goto method. i think it return sequence as the image load. so writeFile method only get the last buffer. Is there other promise method to tackle sequence buffer?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

(async () => {
  const options = {
   product: 'chrome',
   headless: true,
   pipe: true,
   executablePath: 'chrome.exe'
  };

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const response = await page.goto('https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/d/dd/Naruto_Uzumaki%21%21.png/revision/latest?cb=20161013233552');
  
  // save buffer to file
  await fs.writeFile('file.jpg', await response.buffer());
  browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the image is saved. Maybe you need just a proper extension like `file.webp`?

Answer (score 5):

Download with puppeteer is an hell...

for simple downloading in a folder on you pc:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', 
    downloadPath: 'C:\folder...'}); // this set the destionation of file dowloaded by pup.
// then page.goto ....
```

This is a full-example: you can use to dowload any kind of resources, also if a login is required :-)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

(async () => {

let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
let page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://static.wikia.nocookie.net')

// ...eventually login

let fn = async (URI) => {
    // fetch the page from inside the html page
    const res = await fetch(URI, {'credentials': 'same-origin'});

    // attachment; filename="...."; size="1234"
    let str = res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    const regex = /filename="([^"]*)".*size="([^"]*)"/gm;

    let m = regex.exec(str);
    let filename = m?m[1]:null;
    let size = m?m[2]:null;
    let blob = await res.blob()
    let bufferArray = await blob.arrayBuffer();

    var base64String = btoa([].reduce.call(new Uint8Array(bufferArray),function(p,c){return p+String.fromCharCode(c)},''))

    return {base64String, size, filename};
}

let x = await page.evaluate(fn, 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/d/dd/Naruto_Uzumaki%21%21.png/revision/latest?cb=20161013233552')

// x.base64String <- buffer, you can write
// x.filename <- name of file downloaded
// x.size <- size

// console.log(x.blob)

await fs.writeFile('message1.png', x.base64String, {encoding: "base64"})
console.log('ok!')

})().then();
```

Comment: please note that if you use v19> then `_.client` is a method , so base on anser you need to convert `await page._client.send` to `await page._client().send`